# How disable area-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, input, autocomplete, field, formik

In my react app I used Formik form helper but it add area-autocomplete="list", when I try to add that prop react change my added value to "list" again on Focus. Even functions that change that prop didn't help.

Comment: Did you try adding autoComplete="off" ?

Comment: Yes @Oakar I tried almost everything

Comment: It would be better if you can share a code snippet